# Using binary semaphores to synchronize 2 threads C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have an assignment and I have absolutely no idea what to do.  The assignment is to create and use 2 threads and using 2 semaphores (I assumed it would be best to use binary semaphores) sync those threads.  The program is a see-saw simulator.  Person 1 (fred) starts at the ground while Person 2 (wilma) starts in the air.  The max height either person can go is 7 (feet, yards, whatever you want).  When person 2 reaches the ground, she pushes off the ground at 1.5 units/sec while fred can only push off at 1 unit/sec.  Every second (using a sleep) the program needs to print out the current heights of each person.  It needs to run 10 times (time 1 (or round 1) finishes once person 1 has reached the max height and then time 2 (or round 2) finishes once person 1 has returned to the ground).

The code that I have so far is really just the creation, and joining of the 2 threads (and that proved to be somewhat of a challenge because I've never dealt with threads before.  **BTW** this is written in C++).  i understand the concepts of how semaphores work, how they work with protecting a critical section but I just can't figure out the code to actually make it work.  I know that the code I already have isn't much but I'll still put it below for your reference.  Everything that I have researched all takes me back to using mutexes (not semaphores).  If anyone could please help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;
int fredHeight = 1;
int wilmaHeight = 7;

void *fredSee(void *param);
void *wilmaSaw(void *param);
void wait();
bool try_wait();
void signal();

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread1;
  pthread_t thread2;

  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, fredSee, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, wilmaSaw, NULL);

  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

  return 0;
}

void *fredSee(void *param)
{

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *wilmaSaw(void *param)
{

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**EDIT**:
I have been restricted to using semaphores and I don't know how to use them properly.  I've added some more code (see below).  I've added the functionality of printing out the two persons heights and that works perfectly.  I just don't know how to, after going through the second thread, to "switch" back to the first, since that's basically the logic that needs to happen.

**Side-note:** I think that I could just brute force it (even though I don't think I'm supposed to) by just making multiple threads and calling the same functions over and over again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;

double fredHeight = 1;
double wilmaHeight = 7;
int value;

void *fredSee(void *param);
void *wilmaSaw(void *param);
void decrement();
unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);


int main()
{
  pthread_t thread1;
  pthread_t thread2;

  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, fredSee, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, wilmaSaw, NULL);

  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

  return 0;
}

void *fredSee(void *param)
{
  while (fredHeight < 7)
  {
    fredHeight++;
    wilmaHeight--;
    cout << "Fred's Height: " << fredHeight << endl;
    cout << "Wilma's Height: " << wilmaHeight << endl;
  }
  cout << "Going down..." << endl;
  cout << endl;
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *wilmaSaw(void *param)
{
  while (fredHeight > 1)
  {
    wilmaHeight = wilmaHeight + 1.5;
    fredHeight = fredHeight - 1.5;
    cout << "Fred's Height: " << fredHeight << endl;
    cout << "Wilma's Height: " << wilmaHeight << endl;
  }
  cout << "Going up..." << endl;
  cout << endl;
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/*This function I only added because I was watching a video on how to use semaphores
and they said that I need some sort of decrementer and incrementer.
Not sure if I even did it correctly but it compiled so I'm going to
think I did.  It's not actually used anywhere so it's not really doing anything*/
void decrement()
{
  while (value == 0)
  {
    try
    {
      cv.wait(lck, [] {return value == 0;});
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
      cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Posix pthread and mutex work fine, but I recommend using C++ std::thread and std::mutex.  Have you been prohibited from using mutex?  From various places "A semaphore is a generalized mutex.", "A mutex is really a semaphore with value 1."   If mutex is disallowed, use a semaphore in the same style as if a mutex (where only the current owner can signal the semaphore) and initialized to 1.

Comment: The keyword 'simulator', allows you to 'detach' from real time (as in a controller).  A substantially simpler to understand (and debug).  So your next step might be to research 'simulators', seeking some ideas for how to proceed.  There are several kinds, perhaps start with a short list.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN please look at my edit for some changes.  I'm not sure if much will change with your response

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN why not just do a reply (instead of comment) to the question? also i looked at the Posix Process Semaphore and it looks like it's used in C.  Is it also usable in C++?

Comment: "Posix ... looks like it's used in C" -- Posix is an API, and thus can be used by any language capable of submitting calls to it ... C++ handles it trivially.  Any Posix API implementation might be written using any language, maybe even assy for top performance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43145637/2785528

Comment: Have you considered what the output (of your simulation) will look like.  This 'end-point' might help you find your way 'towards the middle' of your effort.